# Mostrar solo un Numero

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, angular7

estoy con `IONIC` y necesito acceder a los contactos del teléfono. Gracias al Plugin Ionic Native Contacts puedo hacer de forma muy sencilla.

El problema es...

1- Hago un bucle para recorrer el array de contactos `contactFound`.

2- Imprimo el nombre del contacto y funciona bien... `{{contact.name.formatted}}`

3- Como cojo el primero numero del teléfono móvil... Como esta abajo funciona correctamente pero me da todos los números del teléfono (home, work, mobile)... lógicamente porque he realizado un loop. He probado con `contact.phoneNumbers[0].value` y no funciona... Solo quiero uno de los números no todos...

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of contactsFound">
            <ion-label>
              <h2>{{contact?.name.formatted}}</h2>

              <h5 *ngFor="let num of contact.phoneNumbers">
                {{num.value}}
              </h5>

            </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

¿Cómo hacer para poner dentro de H5 solo el 1 único número de teléfono?

> SOLUCIÓN, GRACIAS DE TODAS FORMAS

```
        <h5 *ngFor="let num of contact.phoneNumbers; let primero=first">
          <span *ngIf="primero">{{num.value}}</span>
        </h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema está en que haces un nuevo bucle, el cual vuelve a recorrer los números telefónicos debido al `*ngFor` si deseas buscar un número espécifico, esto se haría así

```
<spam *ngFor="let num of contact.phoneNumbers">
            <h5 *ngIf="num.value == valorAComparar">
 </h5> </spam>
```

en este caso solo te mostraría un valor

Comment: No se como puedo usar lo que me dices... hago un bucle para recorrer todos los numeros... Solo quiero uno así que el bucle no sería necesario pero es que esto -- contact.phoneNumbers[0].value -- no funciona así que no se como hacerlo... El IF que pones tampoco se a que te refieres... ¿Con que valor comparo? Si lo que quiero es mostrarlo solo uno de los 3 que se supone que hay en el array phoneNumbers.